# Find object diff with Recursive Function in angular

Tags: angularjs, arrays, recursion

I have 2 functions in my angular controller named loadForm and SaveForm. 
i want to find diff between my Form array and my new array.
So i used object Diff plugin for that. 
This is a preview of 
[My Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7pFV.png)
And this is a preview of my DiffObject result: [changed Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3yJt.png)

i have to save only object change values by a recursive function.
pushing values into a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by checking the Database fields,
It is better than checking the difference of arrays.